# Does this quantum concentration work for both atoms and molecules?

Tags: thermodynamics, atomic-physics, molecules

The quantum concentration $n_Q$ is defined as
$$
n_Q=\left(\frac{MkT}{2\pi\hbar}\right)^{3/2}
$$
it is the particle concentration of a system where the interparticle distance is equal to the thermal de Broglie wavelength. I'm wondering what could be considered as 'particles' in this equation? Can I use this same equation to determine the quantum concentration for both hydrogen atoms and hydrogen molecules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There does not appear to be any reason why not. Consider the number $$n_Q=\left(\frac{MkT}{2\pi\hbar}\right)^{3/2}$$ and the particle concentration of a system $n=\frac{N}{V}$ (particle number per unit volume) of a system, where the interparticle distance equals the thermal de Broglie wavelength. As in this Wiki article [Quantum Concentration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_concentration), when $n\ge n_Q$

"*Quantum effects become appreciable when the particle concentration is greater than or equal to the quantum concentration*"

Both atoms and molecules can have a [thermal de Broglie wavelength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_de_Broglie_wavelength) $$\lambda=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi \hbar^2}{mk_BT}}$$ and even massless particles can have the same given by $$\lambda=\frac{\pi^\frac{2}{3} \hbar c}{k_BT}$$

Consequently, $n_Q$ can be calculated/used for systems containing hydrogen atoms or molecules, or even for more complicated systems like a photon gas.

Comment: Thanks so much:)

Comment: No worries. Good luck with your studies.